# SQL create a computed column from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a computed column where the value comes from another table. The table must be stored in the database.

Existing Table named TABLE 1

```
ID  GROUP ITEM_NO COST_A COST_B
1   1     1001    20.00  30.00
2   1     1002    10.00  25.00
3   2     1005    15.00  25.00
```

In the new table named Table 2, I wish to have the following.
Essentially the GROUP_TOTALCOST is the COST_A plus COST_B for each group

```
Code GROUP(FK) GROUP_TOTALCOST
001  1         85.00
002  2         40.00
```

Is this something I can achieve in an ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN or CREATE TABLE statement?
Thanks

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: anyway answer is No! you cannot have computed column from another table , you might wanna make a view to achieve that

Comment: @eshirvana thanks. If considering all options, what should I do if I want the GROUP_TOTALCOST column to be updated somehow automatically when there is a change in TABLE 1? Do I need to have an UPDATE everytime the costs change?

Comment: View is the preferred way in this case. If you have to go with table by any means you can use trigger in the table 1 which will update the values in table 2

Answer (score 1):

Create a View to get values calculated on the fly:

```
CREATE VIEW <NAME> AS 
SELECT [GROUP],SUM(COST_A + COST_B) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY [GROUP]
```

Alternatively persist the result in a table - but you will have to re-create it if your original table changes:

```
CREATE TABLE <NAME> AS 
SELECT [GROUP],SUM(COST_A+COST_B) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY [GROUP]
```

In both cases you will use `SELECT * FROM <NAME>` to get your data.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot have a computed column based on another table, you can make a view and whenever you select from view It's up to date

here is the syntax you might want to consider if you are using sql server

```
create view yourviewname
as 
select 
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by GROUP) as rownumber ,  GROUP, sum(Cost_A) + sum( COst_B) as GROUP_TOTALCOST
from testx
group by GROUP
```